# How can I alert for pod restarted with prometheus rules

Tags: alert, prometheus, rules

I like to monitor the pods using Prometheus rules so that when a pod restart, I get an alert. I wonder if anyone have sample Prometheus alert rules look like this but for restarting

```
    - alert: KubePodCrashLooping
      annotations:
        message: Pod {{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.pod }} ({{ $labels.container
          }}) is restarting {{ printf "%.2f" $value }} times / 5 minutes.
      expr: |
        rate(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{job="kube-state-metrics"}[15m]) * 60 * 5 > 0
      for: 1h
      labels:
        severity: critical
```

Comment: any update please this is urgent

Answer (score 2):

you can try this (alerting if a container is restarting more than 5 times during the last hour):

```
- alert: PodRestarts
      annotations:
        message: Pod {{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.pod }} ({{ $labels.container
          }}) is restarting {{ printf "%.2f" $value }} times during the last hour. 
      expr: increase(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{container!~"kubernetes-vault-renew"}[1h]) > 5
      labels:
        severity: critical
```